# Apache - How to extend localhost scope e.g. to other drives?

Tags: apache, localhost

In Apache *httpd.conf* file I can set the DocumentRoot value. After setting this, if I view "localhost" in a browser, I can see the folders and files this given folder contains. I cannot "speak" PHP language well yet but I assume that all PHP activities in connection with files and folders are limited to the scope of localhost, so if I handle files with PHP they must be in the folder set as DocumentRoot (or in subfolders of it).

How can I set localhost's scope to a wider range, especially to other drives? My goal is to be able to handle files with PHP on my whole computer (it's a "locahost-only" project so it's not a must to be able to use it on "real" servers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can access any files any where within your computer if you give it the right access permission. You can use absolute paths when locating a file in PHP.

Comment: Thank you! What if I don't know the name of files/folders - I have found the answer here how to get the hierarchy of a directory in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660644/get-the-hierarchy-of-a-directory-with-php. But I want to scan not just a directory but my whole computer. So the question is that how can I read in the list of all partitions in PHP?